# Error in uninstalling node version

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

When i do **nvm ls**

```
->       v4.3.2
         system
default -> 4.3.2 (-> v4.3.2)
node -> stable (-> v4.3.2) (default)
stable -> 4.3 (-> v4.3.2) (default)
iojs -> N/A (default)
```

and when I do nodejs --version
I get `v0.10.25`

How can i get rid of `v0.10.25`?

I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x) followed top two answers. I want to remove 0.10.25 which i installed using `sudo apt-get install nodejs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably missed your *~/.profile* setup or didn't yet executed it after nvm installation. See [this howto](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-an-ubuntu-14-04-server) for example and check that you have somthing like this in your *~/.profile* file:

```
export NVM_DIR="/home/<your_user_name>/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
```

If you have it, try to execute `source ~/.profile` and try again.

After that, if you execute `which node`, it should output something like:

```
/home/<your_user_name>/.nvm/<your_selected_node_version>/bin/node
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of randomly searching for nodejs installation folder
first use `which nodejs` that would give something like `/usr/bin/nodejs`

Now go in `/usr/bin` and use `sudo rm -rf nodejs` to remove nodejs.

Now type `nodejs --version` 
It should come node's version which you installed using nvm.

Comment: though your solution solved my problem but I think steps described by bitifet is correct procedure